# Javascript regexp not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been working on a regexp, that would parse a date from the format of

```
3d 4m 5y
```

to an array, so that I could do some manipulations with it.

I have written a regexp like this:

```
((\d+)([d,m,y]))
```

What this returns is

```
["3d", "3d", "3", "d"]
```

When I believe it should be returning

```
["3d", "3d", "3", "d","4m","4","m"]
```

for the string

```
3d4m
```

It is implemented in my code like this:

```
c=console;
myregexp=/((\d+)([d,m,y]))/g;
//myregexp = new RegExp(regexstring);
c.log(myregexp.exec($("#dateInterval").val()));
```

right now I'm only logging the data, but I do think, that something is wrong here.

Comment: `exec` will probably not group them for you recursively. Are you sure you aren't aiming for `console.log('3d 4m 5y'.match(myregexp));`?

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with your problem, but you should remove the commas from your character class: `[dmy]` is what you want. Otherwise, the comma would also be matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> I believe it should be returning

```
["3d", "3d", "3", "d","4m","4","m"]
```

That's not right.

Calling exec() using a regexp that uses the 'g' option tells it to keep processing matches until it is done. The return array is not a set of all the matches.  It is the set of all the captures, for the final match attempt. On the first iteration, it gets `["3d", "3d", "3", "d"]`.  On the 2nd iteration, it gets `["4m", "4m", "4", "m"]`.  The capture groups from the 1st iteration get replaced.  In other words the '3d' that is in the 1st capture in the 1st iteration gets over-written by the 4 from the 1st capture group in the 2nd iteration, and so on.

To grab all the matches, you can walk the string. like this:

```
function test2()
{
    var value = "3d4m"; // $('#element').val()
    var re="(\\d+)([dmy])";
    var myregexp = new RegExp(re);
    while (value != "")
    {
        say("input: " + value);
        var result = myregexp.exec(value);
        if (result !== null) {
            say("r[1]: " + result[0]);  // 3d on 1st iteration, 4m on 2nd, etc.
            value = value.substr(result[0].length);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could be off base here, but according to w3 schools:

**[exec()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_exec.asp)**

> This method returns the matched text
>   if it finds a match, otherwise it
>   returns null.

**[match()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)**

> This method returns an array of
>   matches, or null if no match is found.

This would lead me to believe that exec() will only return a single result.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zA9Va/) using the two different methods with the same regex statement, yielding different results.